# Graph Not Showing Up when running program (PLOTLY)

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, plotly

When I run my program, it does not throw any errors, however it seems to run as an infinite loop  never finishing execution or showing me the graph output anywhere, when expected output should be a graph with a candlestick chart and multiple lines and volume bar chart:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import chart_studio.plotly as plt

dataframe=\
    web.DataReader('SPY','yahoo',datetime(2020,10,16),datetime(2020,11,16))
dataframe.head()

INCREASING_COLOR = '#17BECF'
DECREASING_COLOR = '#7F7F7F'

data = [ dict(
    type='candlestick',
    open=dataframe.Open,
    high=dataframe.High,
    low=dataframe.Low,
    close=dataframe.Close,
    x=dataframe.index,
    yaxis = 'y2',
    name = 'SPY',
)]

layout = dict()
figure = dict(data=data,layout=layout)

figure['layout'] = dict()
figure['layout']['plot_bgcolor'] = 'rgb(250, 250, 250)'
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = dict( rangeselector = dict( visible = True ) )
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = dict( domain = [0, 0.2], showticklabels = False )
figure['layout']['yaxis2'] = dict( domain = [0.2, 0.8] )
figure['layout']['legend'] = dict( orientation = 'h', y=0.9, x=0.3, yanchor='bottom' )
figure['layout']['margin'] = dict( t=40, b=40, r=40, l=40 )

rangeselector=dict(
    visible=True,
    x=0, y=0.9,
    bgcolor='rgba(150,200,250,0.4)',
    font=dict(size=13),
    buttons=list([
        dict(count=1,
             label='reset',
             step='all'),
        dict(count=1,
             label='1yr',
             step='year',
             stepmode='backward'),
        dict(count=3,
             label='3mo',
             step='month',
             stepmode='backward'),
        dict(count=1,
             label='1mo',
             step='month',
             stepmode='backward'),
        dict(step='all')
    ]))
figure['layout']['xaxis']['rangeselector']=rangeselector

def movingaverage(interval,window_size=10):
    window=np.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
    return np.convolve(interval,window,'same')

movingaverage_y=movingaverage(dataframe.Close)
movingaverage_x=list(dataframe.index)

# Clip the ends
movingaverage_x=movingaverage_x[5:-5]
movingaverage_y=movingaverage_y[5:-5]

figure['data'].append(dict(x=movingaverage_x,y=movingaverage_y,
                           type='scatter',mode='lines',
                           line=dict(width=1),
                           marker=dict(color='#E377C2'),
                           yaxis='y2',name='Moving Average'))

colors=[]
for i in range(len(dataframe.Close)):
    if i!=0:
        if dataframe.Close[i]>dataframe.Close[i-1]:
            colors.append(INCREASING_COLOR)
        else:
            colors.append(DECREASING_COLOR)
    else:
        colors.append(DECREASING_COLOR)

figure['data'].append(dict(x=dataframe.index,y=dataframe.Volume,
                           marker=dict(color=colors),
                           type='bar',yaxis='y',name='Volume'))

# ---------- BOLLINGER BANDS ------------
def bollinger_bands(price,window_size=10,num_of_std=5):
    rolling_mean = price.rolling(window=window_size).mean()
    rolling_std = price.rolling(window=window_size).std()
    upper_band = rolling_mean + (rolling_std * num_of_std)
    lower_band = rolling_mean - (rolling_std * num_of_std)
    return rolling_mean, upper_band, lower_band

bollinger_bands_average,upper_band,lower_band=bollinger_bands(dataframe.Close)
figure['data'].append(dict(x=dataframe.index,y=upper_band,type='scatter',yaxis='y2',
                            line=dict(width=1),
                            marker=dict(color='#ccc'), hoverinfo='none',
                            legendgroup='Bollinger Bands',name='Bollinger Bands'))
figure['data'].append(dict(x=dataframe.index,y=lower_band,type='scatter',yaxis='y2',
                            line=dict(width=1),
                            marker=dict(color='#ccc'), hoverinfo='none',
                            legendgroup='Bollinger Bands',showlegend=False))
# ----------------------------------------

plt.iplot(figure, filename='candlestick',validate=True)
```

Let me know if more information is needed

Comment: have you tried `plt.show()` as the last line of your code?

Comment: yes I have and it doesn't reach it at the end

Comment: put print statements along your code to find where it hangs

Comment: I did that and it run smoothly up until ```plt.iplot(figure, filename='candlestick',validate=True)```

Comment: Have you done `print(figure)` and looked through the dictionary to confirm that everything is formatted properly?

Comment: Are you executing this as a standalone .py file or using something like jupyter notebook?

Comment: i will try this and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** ANSWER ***

`import chart_studio.plotly as plt` requires some time of online compatability so in order to combat this I changed the import to this: `from plotly.offline import plot`

Then in order to be able top see this plot, I changed the final line from:
`plt.iplot(figure,filename='candlestick',validate=True)`
to:

`plot(figure, filename = 'candlestick-test-3.html', validate = False )`

Thus the graph will be created and opened inside your browser!